# Keyboard Module Python

Tags: python, keyboard

i am trying to use the keyboard module to press the **control button** on mac but nothing works, either i am putting in the wrong name or not using the right code.

this is the code that im using at the moment however the **control** part does nothing.

```
keyboard.press_and_release('control + x')
```

i have tried just about every nickname for "control", "ctrl", "CTRL", "Control. i cant think of any more ways it could be written.

Comment: Try using `keyboard.on_press(print)` and press the control button and see what it prints out. Perhaps it recognizes it as a different key on Mac?

Comment: Also, check with both ctrl keys. I have a keyboard that can't do combinations of ctrl + alt + esc if they are all on the left side of the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not usually a Mac user, try the command + x buttons instead (the equivalent of 'cut' on Windows, if memory serves). There are also no spaces – (ctrl+x). If nothing works, be weary Mac OS X support is only experimental https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/.

Comment: i am trying to use my code to automate creating code in the mac OS terminal using **nano** and the command to save it as a file is "control X" and i don't think there is any other way to save a NANO other than "control X". thats basically what i need to make it press "Control X"